# Find all $f$ analytic on unit disc and ctc on closure of disc with given properties.

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all analytic functions $f$ on unit disc $\mathbb{D}$ and continuous on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ with the properties:

1. $|f(z)| = 1$ for $z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$.
2. $f(z) \neq 0$ for all $z \in \overline{\mathbb{D}} \setminus \{0\}$.
3. $f(0) = 0$.

**Attempt:** Condition (1) implies $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$ by max modulus (and $f$ non-constant by (2), (3)). This with (3) allows for Schwarz lemma: $|f(z)| \leq |z|$ and $|f'(z)| \leq 1$. I have a feeling that $f(z) = \lambda z$ for some $\lambda \in \partial \mathbb{D}$ but I'm not sure how to get there. I know I'd need at least one fixed point *inside* the disc.

Comment: Hint: use the condition  |f|=|z|=1 on $\partial\mathbb{D}$ to apply some form of Rouchè theorem

Comment: Your feeling is not completely true: e.g. $f(z)=z^2$ satisfies the conditions too. ($|f'(z)|\le 1$ is unmotivated to apply Schwarz.) Start from 3 and conclude that $f(z)=z^ng(z)$ with some analytical $g$, $g(0)\ne 0$. Now use 1,2 to say more about $g$.

Comment: Well I can conclude now that $g$ has the same properties as $f$ with the exception of (1). So $g: \mathbb{D} \rightarrow \mathbb{D}$ non-vanishing and analytic.

Comment: @Fred (1) holds true as well: $|f(z)|=|z|^n|g(z)|=|g(z)|=1$ on the unit circle.

Comment: Oops, yes I mean (3), thanks!

Comment: @Fred If $g$ is nonvanishing, what can you say about $\frac1{g(z)}$?

Comment: Ah haha nice. Okay so $|1/g| = 1$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ so use Max Modulus to conclude $g$ constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $|f(z)| = 1$ the Maximum Modulus Principle guarantees that $f(\mathbb{D}) \subset \mathbb{D}$. Since $f(0) = 0$ we can write $f(z) = z^{n}g(z)$ for some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and analytic $g$ not vanishing at $0$. Since $f$ has no other zeros, $g$ has no zeros in $\mathbb{D}$. Then $1/g$ is analytic, and $|1/g(z)| = 1$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$ (since $1 = |g(z)| = |z^{n}g(z)| = |f(z)|$ on $\partial \mathbb{D}$). Then $|g(z)| = 1$ inside the disc by Max Modulus, so $g$ must be constant: $g \equiv \lambda \in \partial \mathbb{D}$. Thus $f(z) = \lambda z^{n}$.

Comment: You may also look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product#Finite_Blaschke_products) for the more general case of several zeros within the unit disc.